# Using yeoman-maven-plugin fails to execute build with npm install error

Tags: maven, angularjs, yeoman

I'm trying out the yeoman-maven-plugin on my maven webapp.  When I run "clean install -DskipTests=true -X" I get the following output.  Not sure what's going on as the "yo" directory does exist within the root of my project.  I ran "yo angular --minsafe" within that directory to initialize the app.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.1:build (default) on project map-trucks: Error during : npm install: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/Users/patrick/IdeaProjects/XTL/map-trucks/yo"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.1:build (default) on project map-trucks: Error during : npm install
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during : npm install
    at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:68)
    at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.npmInstall(YeomanMojo.java:44)
    at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.execute(YeomanMojo.java:38)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/Users/patrick/IdeaProjects/XTL/map-trucks/yo"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:319)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
    at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:66)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: So I've determined it works ok from a console, but it's failing when run within IntelliJ...

Comment: Did you find solution Patrick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in the yeoman-maven-plugin.

I think that the problem is that npm is not on the PATH for GUI apps like IntelliJ.
The solution is to create/edit the /**etc/launchd.conf** file and to add npm path (I installed npm with brew then I added /usr/local/bin for npm path and /usr/local/share/npm/bin for packages (yo, grunt, ...)

`setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin`